# terraform get values for variables from yaml list

Tags: yaml, terraform

How can I read the values from the yaml file? I have no more ideas how to do that. This is a super simple example I know, but I still don't get it what the issue is. I need to do this with count not with for_each. The yaml decode part is done by terragrunt.

```
aws:
  -
    accounts: "dev"
    id: "523134851043"
    private_subnets:
      eu-central-1a: "10.44.4.96/27"
      eu-central-1b: "10.44.5.128/27"
      eu-central-1c: "10.44.6.160/27"
  -
    accounts: "prod"
    id: "098453041227"
    private_subnets:
      eu-central-1a: "10.44.7.0/27"
      eu-central-1b: "10.44.8.32/27"
      eu-central-1c: "10.44.9.64/27"
```

```
variable "aws" {
  type = list(object({
    accounts: string
    id: string
    private_subnets: list(object({
      cidr: string
    }))
  }))
}
```

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  count = length(var.aws.accounts[*].private_subnets)

  availability_zone = element(keys(var.aws.accounts[*].private_subnets), count.index)
  cidr_block        = element(values(var.aws.accounts[*].private_subnets), count.index)
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.this.id
```

It produces this error.

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on test.tf line 40, in resource "aws_subnet" "private":
│   40:   count = length(var.aws.accounts[*].private_subnets)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.aws is a list of object, known only after apply
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access
│ attribute "accounts" for a specific element of the list, or across all
│ elements of the list?
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on test.tf line 42, in resource "aws_subnet" "private":
│   42:   availability_zone = element(keys(var.aws.accounts[*].private_subnets), count.index)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.aws is a list of object, known only after apply
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access
│ attribute "accounts" for a specific element of the list, or across all
│ elements of the list?
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on test.tf line 43, in resource "aws_subnet" "private":
│   43:   cidr_block        = element(values(var.aws.accounts[*].private_subnets), count.index)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.aws is a list of object, known only after apply
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access
│ attribute "accounts" for a specific element of the list, or across all
│ elements of the list?
╵
ERRO[0008] 1 error occurred:
    * exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the variable type doesn't match your data and code you try to use. It should be:

```
variable "aws" {
  type = list(object({
    accounts: string
    id: string
    private_subnets: map(string)
  }))
}
```

Then I don't understand why you couldn't use `for_each`. It normally leads code which is easier to understand and maintain, especially when refactoring. `count` will lead to resource recreations if the order of the data changes.

With `for_each` you would only need to make sure to use a unique index string, e.g. `<az>/<cidr>` in this case.

For example:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  # Build a map with unique index.
  # It might be cleaner to extract this to a local variable.
  for_each = merge([
    for account in var.aws : {
      for az, cidr in account.private_subnets :
      "${az}/${cidr}" => { az = az, cidr = cidr }
    }
  ]...)

  availability_zone = each.value.az
  cidr_block        = each.value.cidr
  # ...
}
```

If you really want to use `count`:

```
locals {
  subnets = flatten([
    for account in var.aws : [
      for az, cidr in account.private_subnets : { az = az, cidr = cidr }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  count = length(local.subnets)

  availability_zone = local.subnets[count.index].az
  cidr_block        = local.subnets[count.index].cidr
  # ...
}
```